# Laravel route segment

Tags: laravel, url, routes, laravel-routing

I wanna write a route `Route::get('/{lang}/home', 'ExampleController@get_home')`, so

- if url will be **localhost::8000/home** then redirect to home
- if url will be **localhost::8000/ru/home** then redirect to home

so lang maybe exists or not?

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a regex: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Answer (score 2):

Laravel doesn't allow optional parameter in middle of route. However, you can resolve it by adding 2 route like this

```
Route::get('/home', 'ExampleController@get_home')
Route::get('/{lang}/home', 'ExampleController@get_home')
```

Controller (add $lang optional param in your controller action)

```
class ExampleController extends Controller {

   public function get_home(Request $request, $lang = null){
     ...
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Update your route to:

```
Route::get('/{lang?}/home', 'ExampleController@get_home')
```

Comment: not works, if lang exists in url works else gives page not found

Comment: I think you need to change {lang?} and home places.